# Finding cdf, percentile, variance, and standard deviation from pdf.

Tags: probability, density-function, percentile

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
2(1-\frac{1}{x^2})  & \text{if }1\le x\le2 \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Compute the CDF of X:

$$
\int^X_12(1-\frac{1}{y^2})dy = 2x+\frac{2}{X}-4
$$

So I got 
$$  
F(X) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if }x\lt1 \\ 
2X+\frac{2}{X}-4  & \text{if }1\le X\le2 \\ 
1 & \text{if }x\gt2
\end{cases}
$$
My problem starts here:

It asks to obtain an expression for the (100p)th percentile and the value of the median.

Isn't the given expression 
$$f(x) =
2(1-\frac{1}{x^2}) 
$$
(100p)th percentile?

In order to find median I guess I will have to do
$$
\int^c_12(1-\frac{1}{x^2})dx = 0.5
$$
and then solve for c.

And the expected value which I think:
$$
E(x) = \int^2_1x2(1-\frac{1}{x^2})dx
$$

How do the mean and median of this distribution compare?

Can you help me out with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Be careful with your capitalisations.  $X$ should be your random variable. $x$ should be a value or variable of integration. They are not the same thing.  Don't mix and match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDF is indeed:
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & : x\lt 1 \\ 2x+\frac{2}{x}-4  & : 1\le x < 2 \\ 1 & : 2\le x \end{cases}$$
Note: Be careful with your capitalisations.   $X$ should be your random variable.   $x$ should be a value or variable of integration.   They are not the same thing.   Don't mix and match.

The $100p^{\rm th}$ percentile is the inverse of the CDF:$$ F_X^{-1}(p)=\begin{cases} 1 & ; p<0 \\ \tfrac 1 4(p+\sqrt{~p+8~}\sqrt{~p~}+4) & : 0\leq p < 1\\ 2 & : 1\leq p \end{cases}$$

The median is, of course, the 50th percentile, so $m=F_X^{-1}(0.50)$

The mean is, as you had, $\mathsf E(X)=2\,\int_1^2 x\,(1-\tfrac 1 {x^2})\operatorname d x = 3-\ln 4$

Comment: I apologize because this is such an old answer, but could you briefly show how the inverse of $p = 2x + \frac{1}{x} -4$ is $x = \frac{1}{4}(p + \sqrt{p+x}\sqrt{p} + 4)$? Do you convert $p = 2x + \frac{1}{x} -4$ to $2x^2 -px -4x + 1 = 0$ and factor? If so, I'm unsure how to factor it.

Comment: Just use the quadratic formula, @RTF $$2x^2 -(p+4)x +\mathbf 2 =0 \implies x=\dfrac{(p+4)\pm\sqrt{(p+4)^2-16}}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a way "by hand", but now that you mention the obvious I see how to complete the square.